# Issue with fetching data from python handler to javascript using jinja2 and google app engine

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

I am working on a python based Google App Engine project.

And in that I was trying to send **data(python list)** from **python handler to javascript using jinja2** but cannot receive data in javascript.

I even tried to send simple key-value instead of list and json but that too didn't worked.

Here is my code for python handler :

```
mainDataList=[]

keyList = ['key1','key2','key3']
valueList = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']

mainDataList.append(keyList)
mainDataList.append(valueList)

template_values={
    'keyList':mainDataList[0],
    'valueList':mainDataList[1],
}

template = jinja_environment.get_template('main.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

Code inside head tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var keyListToPopulate = {{ keyList | safe }};
        var valueListToPopulate = {{ valueList | safe }};
    </script>
```

Can you please help me with the error I am making.

Comment: And what does the rendered html/js look like ?  What error are you seeing if any ?  No one is ion a position to run your code, you need to provide more information

Comment: try this 
var keyListToPopulate = {{ keyList|escape_js|safe }};

Answer (score 0):

Putting data into inline javascript like that is just string processing.  You need to put the right string into your template variables.  `json.dumps()` produces the string that you need.  Something like this should work:

```
template = jinja_environment.get_template('main.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render({"keyList":json.dumps(range(5)),
                                         "valueList":json.dumps(["A", "B"])}
                                        ))
```